# ESP8266 Arduino EEPROM can only use the first 4KiB flash data?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

The standard arduino `EEPROM.write(address, value)` is a bit different on ESP8266. You need to specify the size of the "sector" and commit. [ESP8266 EEPROM](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html#eeprom])

```
EEPROM.begin(size);
EEPROM.write(addr, val);
EEPROM.commit();
```

`addr` must be between `0` and `size`. [ESP8266 EEPROM.cpp L100-L101](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/EEPROM/EEPROM.cpp#L100-L101).

`EEPROM.begin` allocates that amount of memory into the RAM (even if you only need to write one byte!) and `size` must be between `0` and `4096`. [ESP8266 EEPROM.cpp L54-L65](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/EEPROM/EEPROM.cpp#L54-L65), [spi_flash_geometry.h](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/tools/sdk/include/spi_flash_geometry.h#L8-L13).

If I understand correctly, ESP8266 does not have an internal flash memory. The module ESP-12E has an external 4 MiB flash (512 KiB). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266

So, the ESP8266 EEPROM library only allows to use only the first 4KiB flash data. Why is this? How can I use the rest of the 512 KiB of the ESP-12 module? Or how can I use the standard Arduino EEPROM library?

Answer (score 0):

The flash memory (external) [is used for program and data](https://github.com/esp8266/esp8266-wiki/wiki/Memory-Map#spi-flash-rom-layout-without-ota-upgrades). On larger flash memory two banks are reserved for program to enable OTA Upload. In data section, the flash can contain [a file system](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html). The size of the [emulated EEPROM](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html#eeprom) is limited to fit on flash between file system and SDK settings.

A picture from the "ESP8266 SDK Getting Started Guide":
[image]

Comment: So, if I want to use more 4Kb, I need to use the filesystem? I would prefer to ignore the file system, and use a EEPROM library for all the remaining data space (instead of the limited 4Kb space). How could I achieve this?

Comment: this the size limit is in Espressif SDK (not open source) where the flash regions are defined. btw: the library holds a copy of the EEPROM image in RAM.

Comment: if you want store arrays or structures it is simple to do with SPIFFS. in my project I have a part where I store data to EEPROM on AVR, but to file on SAMD (no eeprom).  it is `EEPROM.put(EVENTS_EEPROM_ADDR, events);` versus `file.write((byte*) events, sizeof(events));` https://github.com/jandrassy/Regulator/blob/master/Regulator/Events.ino

Comment: Ok, I give up using the fast and convenient EEPROM library, and I will use the SPIFFS instead. Thanks.